# Why dynamic programming and naive solutions taking same execution time?

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

I'm trying implement simple solution for rod cutting problem. Below is the code for naive and dynamic programming solutions,

```
public static int rodCutNaive(int[] a, int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return a[0];
    }
    int q = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        int optimalCut = a[i - 1] + rodCutNaive(a, n - i);
        if (q < optimalCut) {
            q = optimalCut;
        }
    }
    return q;
}

public static int rodCutDPBottomUp(int[] a, int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return a[0];
    }
    int[] s = new int[a.length];
    s[0] = a[0];

    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        s[i - 1] = a[i - 1];
        for (int j = 1; j <= i - 1; j++) {
            int optimalCut = a[j - 1] + s[i - j - 1];
            if (s[i - 1] < optimalCut) {
                s[i - 1] = optimalCut;
            }
        }
    }

    return s[n - 1];
}
```

And I tested with below method,

```
public void testRodCutEfficiency() {
    int[] a = { 1, 5, 8, 9, 10, 17, 17, 20, 22, 25, 26, 29, 34, 35, 39, 45,
            46, 47, 50, 51 };

    long t1 = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        Rod.rodCutNaive(a, a.length);
    long t2 = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        Rod.rodCutDPBottomUp(a, a.length);
    long t3 = System.nanoTime();

    System.out.println("Problem size = " + a.length);
    System.out.println("Naive = " + (t2 - t1));
    System.out.println("DP    = " + (t3 - t2));
}
```

Output:

```
Problem size = 20
Naive = 7989627046
DP    = 7913165707
```

May be compiler doing some kind of tail recursion optimization with naive version or is it possible that JVM remebers solutions to previous calls of methods?

Oh, Sorry guys. It's a copy paste mistake. I called same method both the times. Now I've changed it and  new output is,

```
Problem size = 20
Naive = 7764056945
DP    = 1324966
```

I tried to delete the question but it already has answers.

Comment: What is naive is your microbenchmarking. There are many precautions to follow. Check out the Google Caliper library, that's the simplest way to get (semi-)reliable results.

Comment: There's no tail recursion here.

Comment: dude, you're running the same recursion method twice :)

Comment: Well, these things happen!! :)

Comment: Yup, don't worry about it. It's useful to accept an answer though so other users know not to spend too much time looking at the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling rodCutNaive both times.

Answer (score 2):

> May be compiler doing some kind of tail recursion optimization with naive version or is it possible that JVM remebers solutions to previous calls of methods?

The `javac` compiler does almost no optimisations, however the JIT optimises code after it has iterated 10,000 times which can ipact your result.

The HotSpot JVM doesn't support tail recursion optimisation and it doesn't remember previous results.

If I run the test repeatedly I see small improvement from

```
Problem size = 20
Naive = 5792466746
DP    = 8779592
```

to

```
Problem size = 20
Naive = 5701799026
DP    = 472377
```

Comment: Thanks for the info on JVM, was wondering about that for some time.

Comment: Thanks! The performance of DP solution *significantly* (~20 times) increased after repeated execution. It seems branch prediction played a role here (or am I missing something?).

Comment: The JVM optimises heavily used code in stages so you may not get the best result on the first few (thousand) runs.

Answer (score 1):

So yeah, basically, if you change the second benchmark loop to benchmark the dynamic method, you get this drastic speedup:

> Problem size = 20
>
> Naive = 3838585219
>
> DP    = 798526